# How to get a list to list a list as a list and not a str?

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, loops

I am writing a program in python 3 to organize my music library, and am running into a problem making lists.
I am trying to iterate the list rather than write an 'if' statement for every single codec, but when i try to add to the list listed in listList, it calls it a string rather then a list.
I have the print statements at the end to troubleshoot.

```
import os

listList = []
codecList = ('.mp3', '.flac', '.wav') #add codecs here
for c in codecList:
    listList += [c[1:len(c)]+'List']
for L in listList:          
    L = []        
rootDir = '/home/***/Desktop/album'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for name in fileList:         
        ext = os.path.splitext(name)[-1].lower()
        for (l, c) in zip(listList, codecList):
            if c == ext:
                l.append(name)
                print(l)
                print(type(l))
```

The print statements at the end print: "mp3List\ class 'str'" (if it finds only 1 mp3 of course).
basically, I am wondering how to get the print(type(l)) at the end to return class 'list' instead of class 'str' so that I can use the iteration to add the files to their corresponding lists.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `for L in listList:          
    L = []` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop

```
for L in listList:
    L = []
```

does nothing.  `L` here is a local variable which is set to `[]`, it doesn't refer to the location in `listList` to set that element to `[]`.  If you want your elements of `listList` to be named, what you actually want is probably a dictionary, not a list.  That would look something like:

```
import os

listList = {}
codecList = ('.mp3', '.flac', '.wav') #add codecs here
for c in codecList:
    listList[c[1:len(c)]+'List'] = []
rootDir = '/home/***/Desktop/album'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for name in fileList:         
        ext = os.path.splitext(name)[-1].lower()
        for (l, c) in zip(listList, codecList):
            if c == ext:
                listList[l].append(name)
```

Comment: Thank-you! after some trial and error, your answer got it working.

Comment: I definitely am missing fundamental understanding of dictionaries, looks like I have a new goal.

Comment: @IsaacCrockett Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you so that the community can see that it is solved.